# Is it possible in EF6 to have a single DbSet<T> that exists only in memory while the rest are real tables?

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbcontext, in-memory-database

I have a `DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }` that has a fairly typical Entity Framework Accounts table created from it. It has a couple of references in the `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` due to foreign keys in other tables and over 70 references throughout the code where it's used as you might expect (LINQ, Fluent API, etc).

I'd like to source the data that normally would come from the Accounts table from an outside source without having to change any of the other code referencing that DbSet, besides perhaps removing the FKs if necessary.

Ideally it should still function entirely as before, like a normal DbSet, but I need to fetch and provide the data on the fly from another source other than the table.

Working with Entity Framework Core I have seen the concept of an in-memory database used, at least for testing. I don't know if this functionality exists in Entity Framework 6, or if it does if there is any way for me to harness it or use it for only a single table.

In theory I could simply add code that updates/refreshes the data in the in-memory table at just the right times, meanwhile the rest of the tables still exist in the database as before (minus perhaps a few FKs because I'm not sure how that would work in this scenario, but let's assume getting rid of the FKs is a minor issue for now).

Does anyone know if such a thing is possible?

Comment: What I understand from your description there's no reason for the `Accounts` property to be a `DbSet` because it is not mapped in the EF model, so it can never be used in one LINQ statement with mapped entities (in `join`s or navigation properties). Also, you can connect a `DbContext` to only one database. I think it would be very unnatural to even have this alien data source in your context class, easy to forget that it requires special treatment.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree, this is not the best solution, but it could be the least expensive one if I can pull it off...

Answer (score -1):

I understand you are trying to get the benefits of EF/LINQ by tricking it into thinking that the data is from a source other than your primary data source.  I tend to agree with GertArnold that this would probably be problematic to opt for a solution like you described.

Wouldn't it make sense to instead have another mechanism in place which updates your primary data from the secondary source so that you can be more consistent with EF?  Is there some reason why you would not want to have this data replicated/synced with the primary data source for the application?

Comment: I think this should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Seems fair enough.  I lack the prestige required to leave a comment.  At any rate, Good luck finding a solution.  Sometimes we get an idea in our head and keep banging away on a problem when an easier way is right in front of us so I was just trying to help.  To me it seems a genuine solution would be to simply import the data since that is probably a more common way to reap the EF reward.

Comment: I understand, I was more just letting you know in case a mod deletes your answer sometime for not being a direct answer to the question (it can happen) and then you might be annoyed because you took time to write it, don't want you to learn the hard way! Thanks for your input for sure.